How many Integers in the range [0-n] contain at least one 9 in their decimal representation?
Is there a universal formula for how you could work this out?
This is a part of a coding problem I'm attempting to solve and simple solutions like going through each integer and checking if it contains the number 9 is way too slow.
closest I've got so far (working in c#) is this:
using System;
using System.Numerics;

public static class Kata {
  
  public static BigInteger Nines(BigInteger n) 
  { 
    BigInteger a = 0;
    for (BigInteger i = 0; i < BigInteger.Parse((Math.Floor(Math.Log10((double)n))+1).ToString()); i++)
    {
      long c = (long)((Math.Floor((double)n /Math.Pow(10,(double)i)) % 10));
      a = c < 9 ? (long)(((double)c*(Math.Pow(9,(double)i))) + (double)a) : (long)(c*(Math.Pow(9,(double)i)));
    }
    return n-a;
  }
}

however I noticed that when n=3950 for example, I begin getting incorrect values (for this specific case the function returns 1034 instead of 1035 and I'm not sure where I've gone wrong. The error gets even bigger for larger values of n)

Does this answer your question? How to check if an integer includes a certain number in c#

@nbk The OP is wanting a formula so they don't have the check each number individually.

@SimonGoater  please check all answers first before commenting

@nbk I thought I did. Which answer doesn't need all numbers to be checked individually?

The error you see is simply caused by rounding errors (using double will always do that).

Let's say that your input, n, has k digits, and that the leading digit is d.
Then, we're considering all numbers with up to k-1 digits and some (possibly all) with exactly k.
For the numbers with up to k-1 digits, we can allow leading zeros and then think of numbers as having exactly k digits, some with leading zeros. Since there are 10 digits there are 10^(k-1) of these, and since there are 9 digits other than '9', there are 9^(k-1) of these which don't have a 9, therefore there are 10^(k-1) - 9^(k-1) which do have a 9.
Now we need to consider numbers with exactly k digits. Say the leading digit is d. Then the set of all k-digit numbers with a leading digit between 1 & d-1 also has 10^(k-1) - 9^(k-1) members with at least one 9.
If d is a 9 then the rest is easy, just count all k-digit numbers with a leading 9 that are at most n.
If d is smaller than 9 then recurse on n with the leading digit removed.
E.g. n = 234, so d = 2, k = 3
2-digit numbers: 10^2 - 9^2 = 100 - 81 = 19. These are: 9, 19, 29, 39, 49, 59, 69, 79, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99.
3-digit numbers with a leading digit between 1 & 1: There are 1 of these, which gets us another 19 (each elt of the above list, plus 100).
Recursion: repeat the above for n = 34 (we have removed the leading 2).
I don't know c#, so here's Ruby code, which you can read as pseudocode.
def f(n)
  # n = input
  # k = num digits
  # d = leading digit
  
  # confirm input >= 0 & answer basic 1-digit questions directly
  return -1 if n < 0 # invalid input
  return 0 if n < 9
  return 1 if n == 9
 
  # calculate k (num digits) and d (leading digit)
  k = Math.log10(n).to_i + 1
  d = n / 10 ** (k-1)
  
  # Start with all k-1-digit numbers 
  ans = 10 ** (k-1) - 9 ** (k-1)
  
  # Next, multiply this by d to account for leading digits 0 through d-1
  ans *= d
  
  # Next, handle the leading digit differently depending on whether or not it's a 9.
  
  if d == 9
    ans += n - (9 * 10 ** (k-1) - 1)
  else
    ans += f(n - d * (10 ** (k-1)))
  end
  return ans
end

...and here's output for n up to 100.
1.upto(99) do |n|
  puts "#{n}, #{f(n)}"
end

1, 0
2, 0
3, 0
4, 0
5, 0
6, 0
7, 0
8, 0
9, 1
10, 1
11, 1
12, 1
13, 1
14, 1
15, 1
16, 1
17, 1
18, 1
19, 2
20, 2
21, 2
22, 2
23, 2
24, 2
25, 2
26, 2
27, 2
28, 2
29, 3
30, 3
31, 3
32, 3
33, 3
34, 3
35, 3
36, 3
37, 3
38, 3
39, 4
40, 4
41, 4
42, 4
43, 4
44, 4
45, 4
46, 4
47, 4
48, 4
49, 5
50, 5
51, 5
52, 5
53, 5
54, 5
55, 5
56, 5
57, 5
58, 5
59, 6
60, 6
61, 6
62, 6
63, 6
64, 6
65, 6
66, 6
67, 6
68, 6
69, 7
70, 7
71, 7
72, 7
73, 7
74, 7
75, 7
76, 7
77, 7
78, 7
79, 8
80, 8
81, 8
82, 8
83, 8
84, 8
85, 8
86, 8
87, 8
88, 8
89, 9
90, 10
91, 11
92, 12
93, 13
94, 14
95, 15
96, 16
97, 17
98, 18
99, 19

.. and finally, the OP's example:
> f(3950)
=> 1035


The fastest way to solve this problem is to answer a different question first:  How many base-9 representations are <= the decimal representation of n?
Obviously there are n non-zero decimal representations <= n, so if there are x non-zero base-9 representations, then there are n-x decimal representations that aren't base-9 representations, because they contain the digit 9.
Let's do 350, for example.  If that was base-9, then it would be 3*81 + 5*9 = 288.  The number of numbers with a 9 <= 350 is therefore 350-288 = 62.
Easy... almost.  If n actually has a 9 in it, then you need to reduce it to the next lower valid base-9 representation, by replacing the first 9 and all following digits with 8.  3950, for example, becomes 3888.
Now we can calculate 3950 - (3*9*9*9 + 8*9*9 + 8*9 + 8) = 1035 and we're done.
In C#:
    public static int f(int n) {
        bool sawNine = false;
        int base9 = 0;
        foreach (char c in n.ToString()) {
            if (c=='9') {
                sawNine = true;
            }
            base9 = base9 * 9 + (sawNine ? 8 : (int)c-'0');
        }
        return n - base9;
    }


Very cool. Where does this algorithm come from?

It's original, as far as I know.

Even cooler. :)

I am thinking a little left field perhaps but you could try regular expressions on a string which represents the largeInt.
from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match?view=net-8.0#examples

If the Regex.Match method fails to match the regular expression
pattern, it returns a Match object that is equal to Match.Empty. You
can use the Success property to determine whether the match was
successful. The following example provides an illustration.

using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...
...

string input= n.toString(); //your large int

string pattern = @"9";

Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
     
if (match.success) {
 //DONE!
} 


That merely provides a way to detect if an int contains the digit 9. But that isn't what the OP is asking for.
